# How to make layouts load more efficiently? Or keep them cached for fast access?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with about 400 table rows to display data. On a mid-range device it takes about 5 seconds to render.

Is there a way to keep the layout cached so that when the user re-loads the data after viewing one row in more detail, it won't take another 5 seconds to re-render.

Comment: You should be using an AdapterView with an customized Adapter so that it will only need to load the Views currently visible on the screen.

Comment: You haven't described your case but I think a ListView would be a much better solution because it will load the rows from the Adapter as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView with a custom adapter is the solution.